# DB Data retrieval for variable number of inputs using OJDBC

Tags: java, ojdbc

I use OJDBC to retrieve Data from Database to a given set of Primary keys. To make the algorithm efficient I restrict my looping to the given set instead of retrieving the whole table.

I do it that way

```
for (Integer customer : customers){
            String selectStatement= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE customerID ="+customer;
            processCustomer(selectStatement,statement);
        }
        connection.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
```

processCustomer Method processes the Query and fills a HashMap according to my needs.

I believe this is not the best practice because I hit the DB for every customer (can reach 100k) and it takes a lot of time to finish the process.

What is the most efficient way to do it

Comment: you can use preparestament or SELECT * FROM table WHERE customerID in (customer1,customer2,customer3...customern);

Comment: Naren, I thought about that. However sets in DB are restricted to 1000 only. Should I implement a method that does ORing for several sets of 1000?

Comment: Even that gives you performance issue.. generally u wont use all the customer(100k) details every time... hit the db for 100 customers and use it den hit for next 100 ..to make it efficient